# How do i determine if running process is started by system or by user using c#

Tags: c#

I have problem with getting specific name of process, the problem with the process is i want to list out those process which is started by user. If the process is already running while start our PC then it should not list out.

I use this c# code for getting process name

```
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process: " + theprocess.ProcessName);
}
```

but it shows me all the running process. But i need to filter this process list.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question. Do you mean processes started by the system account vs. user account? Or do you also mean processes auto-started when the user logs in vs. processes they launch via user action? In the latter case, it will be almost impossible, since processes started at login can launch other processes...

Comment: I mean if you see the process list you can find something like **Google Chrome (32 bit)** which is **started by user** and something like **HD Audio Background Process** which is started when **we start our PC**. I just want to track application which is started by user like Google Chrome (32 bit). But not Only one process. I want to list out all those process like **Google Chrome (32 bit)**.

Comment: The problem is that some of these can be started by Windows via, for example, the Run key in the registry. If I put Chrome.exe in there, it will autostart, but you won't be able to tell by looking at the process list. If you want only system processes you might be able to get a good list, but many 'system' processes like background tasks and driver UIs can also look like regular programs to Windows.

Comment: But how can get only user started application list and store in a text file?

Comment: That's my point, you aren't defining "user started application" precisely enough to know. The system doesn't keep track of what was autostarted or started by an already running process vs. what was, say, double clicked on to start.